# Cypress can't find Material-UI's textarea

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, cypress, react-testing-library

I'm building a React app. I use Material-UI version 3.9.3 for my components and Cypress with Cypress Testing Library for my E2E tests.

I have a multiline `<TextField />` for which I want to write some tests. When you give the `multiline` prop to TextField it renders for some reason three `textarea` tags. One of these has a visibility of hidden, but still contains a value. There is also a visible one containing the value, but further down in the tree.

```
<TextField
  id="outlined-name"
  label="Name"
  className={classes.textField}
  value={this.state.name}
  onChange={this.handleChange('name')}
  margin="normal"
  variant="outlined"
  multiline={true}
/>
```

When I try to target it with the cypress tests, they fail because they say the element isn't visible:

```
it('inputs some new values but resets them', () => {
  cy.visit('/');
  cy.getByDisplayValue(/lena/i).type('{backspace}nard');
  cy.getByDisplayValue(/inner five/i).select('Distants');

  cy.queryByDisplayValue(/lena/i).should('not.exist');
  cy.getByDisplayValue(/lennard/i).should('exist');

  cy.getByText(/saving/i).should('exist');

  cy.getByDisplayValue(/lena/i).should('exist');
  cy.queryByDisplayValue(/lennard/i).should('not.exist');
  cy.getByText(/saved/i).should('exist');
});
```

Throws:

```
Error:       CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.type() failed because this element is not visible:

<textarea aria-hidden="true" class="MuiPrivateTextarea-textarea-221 MuiPrivateTextarea-shadow-222" readonly="" rows="1" tabindex="-1">Lena</textarea>

This element '<textarea.MuiPrivateTextarea-textarea-221.MuiPrivateTextarea-shadow-222>' is not visible because it has CSS property: 'visibility: hidden'

Fix this problem, or use {force: true} to disable error checking.
```

How can I get this test to pass while still providing reliable information?

Comment: Please show the code for the actual TextField with the problem (corresponding to the cypress test code and error message you included). The one currently in your question isn't `multiline` and doesn't have placeholder text of "Search...". Also, what version of Material-UI are you using?

Comment: @RyanCogswell Sorry, I copied the code wrong. Now it is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple main options. One option is to primarily leverage `getByLabelText` to get the element. The label is tied to the appropriate, visible element of the three so it works reliably. Then just verify the value of the textarea rather than using the value to get the element.

Example:

```
    it('inputs some new values but resets them', () => {
        cy.visit('https://50wv5x5p1x.codesandbox.io/');
        cy.getByLabelText("Name").invoke("val").should("eq", "lena");
        cy.getByLabelText("Name").type('{backspace}nard');
        cy.getByLabelText("Name").invoke("val").should("eq", "lennard");
    });
```

Another option would be to use version 4 of Material-UI. The [first beta version](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/releases/tag/v4.0.0-beta.0) was released today and the first stable release is targeted for mid-May. Textareas have been completely reworked in v4 and no longer render the two hidden textareas, so the following just works:

```
    it('inputs some new values but resets them', () => {
        cy.visit('https://6lj3ymm9qw.codesandbox.io/');
        cy.getByDisplayValue(/lena/i).type('{backspace}nard');
        cy.queryByDisplayValue(/lena/i).should('not.exist');
        cy.getByDisplayValue(/lennard/i).should('exist');
    });
```

Comment: Thank you Ryan. I chose to upgrade to the beta version 

Comment: Looks like you mixed cypress with react-testing-library

Comment: @AlonDahari No, this is using [Cypress Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/cypress-testing-library/intro) as indicated in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Try with inputProps:

```
<TextField
  inputProps={{
    'id': "outlined-name"
  }}
  label="Name"
  className={classes.textField}
  value={this.state.name}
  onChange={this.handleChange('name')}
  margin="normal"
  variant="outlined"
  multiline={true}
/>
```

and then you get it with the id:

```
cy.get('[id="outlined-name"]')
```