# Cypress: how to access third party component?

Tags: angular, cypress

In Cypress I usually access DOM elements with data-test-id attributes. They are hard coded in html.

Exemple:

```
<div data-test-id="my-div"></div>
```

then

```
cy.get('[data-test-id=my-div]').click();
```

But I can't use this method because the app I'm working on uses third party libraries to generate some third party components. 
A few examples: ngx-datable, full-calendar...

Therefore the html is not directly accessible to create data-test-id attributes. I don't want to generate a click based on an x/y position cause I don't think this would be a reliable alternative with various screen sizes. Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a lot of components it's enough to just access the parent, to basically:

```html
<some-component data-cy="foo" />
```

In more complex case where you have to access the inner structure, I'd try to keep it a independent of the structure as possible. So if you can go for class tags first, then component types or in the worst case IDs.  Then use the `data-cy` on the outer component and then using `find` to traverse down into the structure (I'd recommend using `find` no matter what)

**Examples**

If you have a form component that create the input and label, do:

```html
<some-form-component label="foo" model="blah" data-cy="foo" />
```

If the component have the classes (**preferred**) `form-label` and `form-input`, then select them using:

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="foo"]').find('.form-label')
// and
cy.get('[data-cy="foo"]').find('.form-input')
```

if the component (**fallback**) only wraps the normal raw types, but have no sensible classes to use, then do:

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="foo"]').find('label')
// and
cy.get('[data-cy="foo"]').find('input')
```

and if the only thing you have is IDs (**don't do this, unless you have no other option**) then select by the IDs:

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="foo"]').find('#label')
// and
cy.get('[data-cy="foo"]').find('#input')
```

In the last case with the IDs consider finding other components, risking having the same ID on a html page is bad.

**When rendering is weird**
Some frameworks will do seemingly obscure things. One thing that has come to my attention is utilizing multiple inputs for a component. In that case `cy.getByLabelText` might be your way out per the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55896540/1441857

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the **shadow DOM** solved my problem:

```
cy.get("[data-cy=input-field] sdx-input")
  .shadow()
  .find("input")
  .type("Text");
```

The 3rd-party components I am using generates a child in the shadow DOM. To access it, I have to use the `.shadow()` command.

My 3rd-party input component looks like this:

[Screenshot of 3rd-party component in Chrome Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgAQg.png)

[Screenshot of 3rd-party component in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL2E2.png)

Detailed guide (what I did):

1. Add selector to parent component (`data-cy=input-field`)
2. Find 3rd-party component and step into it (`data-cy=input-field sdx-input`)
3. Add `.shadow()` command
4. Find final input field in the shadow DOM in your 3rd-party component (`.find("input")`)

Link to Cypress Doc: [shadow](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/shadow)